# AppEngine LEPL parser.py SyntaxError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, parsing, deployment, lepl

In the development environment, it works great. But after deploying to AppEngine, it breaks. Included necessary files in the project.

LEPL 5.1.3 is being used.

Breakage:

```
<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: invalid syntax (parser.py, line 182)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~roo-net/4-0.361574419262849513/controllers/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    from controllers import users as Users
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~roo-net/4-0.361574419262849513/controllers/users.py", line 15, in <module>
    from lepl.apps.rfc3696 import Email
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~roo-net/4-0.361574419262849513/lepl/__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from lepl.contrib.matchers import SmartSeparator2
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~roo-net/4-0.361574419262849513/lepl/contrib/matchers.py", line 41, in <module>
    from lepl.matchers.derived import Optional
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~roo-net/4-0.361574419262849513/lepl/matchers/derived.py", line 38, in <module>
    from lepl.matchers.combine import And, DepthFirst, BreadthFirst, \
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~roo-net/4-0.361574419262849513/lepl/matchers/combine.py", line 45, in <module>
    from lepl.matchers.core import Literal
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~roo-net/4-0.361574419262849513/lepl/matchers/core.py", line 44, in <module>
    from lepl.core.parser import tagged
```

Super confused with this error message given by appengine. I look at the line 182 in parser.py and it looks fine... great, even. Really beautiful stuff.

...

```
          else:
                    if m_value: m_value.yield_(value)
                    yield value
                # this allows us to restart with a new evaluation
                # (backtracking) if called again.
                value = main
    except StopIteration as exception: # line 182
        if exception_being_raised:
            raise
        # otherwise, we will propagate this value
        value = exception
        exception_being_raised = True
        if m_value: m_value.exception(value)
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may be developing using a Python > 2.5, but are deploying to Python 2.5. (Check the `runtime` in your `app.yaml`). The `as` syntax for `except` came along after Python 2.5.